# json_decode() returns null, even though file_get_contents() works perfectly, even though json is valid

Tags: php, json, jsondecoder

Hi everyone i am reading some data from a txt-file with php using

`file_get_contents('../../Datafiles/allThreads.txt');`

this returns the following string

```
[{"OP":"ding","threadName":"","content":"","ID":6}]
```

when i try to vaildate with lint, I have no issues, so the json is valid.

But the problem is that when i call json_decode it keeps returning null:

```
$currentThreadasList = json_decode('../../Datafiles/allThreads.txt');
```

Why is this happening? im following all the rules?

Comment: you have to specify contents under json_decode, not path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like:

```php
//storing json contents in a variable.
$json_contents = file_get_contents('../../Datafiles/allThreads.txt');

//decode json
$currentThreadasList = json_decode($json_contents, TRUE)
```

#### Edit-1:

Have you tried the following:

```php
$currentThreadasList = json_decode(file_get_contents('../../Datafiles/allThreads.txt'), TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this piece of code

```php
$currentThreadasList = json_decode('../../Datafiles/allThreads.txt');
```

doesn't work because the first parameter to `json_decode` needs to be a JSON string, not a path. Just pass the content of the file as parameter like:

```php
$yourJsonDecodedArray = json_decode(file_get_contents('../../Datafiles/allThreads.txt'), TRUE);
```